# Python - create inherited class attribute under condition

Tags: python, class, attributes

```
class WineComponents(object):

    def __init__(self, aroma, body, acidity, flavor, color):
        self.aroma = aroma
        self.body = body
        self.acidity = acidity
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.color = color
```

which can be instantiated like so:

```
wine = Color(aroma='80%', body='30%', acidity='35%', flavor='90%', color='Red')
```

then I want to be able to create specific classes that will inherit `WineComponents()`:

```
class Color(WineComponents): 

      def receipe(self):
          pass
```

and also to have its own attributes, under certain conditions, like so:

```
class Color(WineComponents):

     if self.color == 'Red':
        region  = 'France'
        type = 'Bordeaux'

     def receipe(self):
         pass
```

calling the attribute with:

```
print wine.region
```

but this does not work:

```
 if self.color == 'Red':
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

is there a workaround this?

Comment: if you really want that, you can do the logic for `if self.color == 'Red'` etc in `__init__()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my five pence:

```
class WineComponents(object):

def __init__(self, aroma, body, acidity, flavor, color):
    self.aroma = aroma
    self.body = body
    self.acidity = acidity
    self.flavor = flavor
    self.color = color


class Color(WineComponents):
    def __init__(self, aroma, body, acidity, flavor, color):
        super(Color, self).__init__(aroma, body, acidity, flavor, color)
        if self.color == 'Red':
            self.region = 'France'
            self.type = 'Bordeaux'

    def receipe(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wine = Color(aroma='80%', body='30%', acidity='35%', flavor='90%', 
    color='Red')
    print (wine.region, wine.type)
```

Comment: this solution is more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a property

```
class Wine(object):
    def __init__(self, aroma, body, acidity, flavor, color):
        self.aroma = aroma
        self.body = body
        self.acidity = acidity
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.color = color

    @property
    def region(self):
        if self.color == 'Red':
            return 'France'
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('unknown region for this wine')
```

Which can be called as this:

```
>>> wine = Wine(aroma='80%', body='30%', acidity='35%', flavor='90%', color='Red')
>>> wine.region
'France'
```